# Is there a less file for the bootstrap theme in tablesorter?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icons, tablesorter

The `theme.less` file that comes with tablesorter seems to be for the non-bootstrap themes - is there a `.less` file that was used to create the bootstrap theme in table sorter? Having some difficulty recreating a bootstrap css with different color schemes. In particular, I need the white icons that would be used for a dark theme, for example for the `.unsorted` icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just modified the basic `theme.less` theme to work with Bootstrap.

Check out the [demo here](http://codepen.io/Mottie/pen/Ltzpi).. so for now, copy the less code from that demo. I'll add the actual file in the next update.